# Magnetic levitation using permanent magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, superconductivity, levitation

Is it possible to achieve magnetic levitation (rail) using permanent magnets? So no electromagnets or superconductivity. If yes, how? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, yes, but practically speaking, no.

The levitation system of maglev trains generally only relies on static fields, which hypothetically could be reproduced with permanent magnets. You can even make [models](https://youtu.be/KQH2UhHss6c) using permanent magnets. However, for actual practical systems (at least for human transport), permanent magnets are too weak - [this source](http://www.supraconductivite.fr/en/index.php?p=applications-trains-maglev-more#:%7E:text=Permanent%20currents%20of%20about%20700,than%20the%20earth%20magnetic%20field.) gives (averaged effective?) field strengths of 5 T needed for their maglev system, while permanent magnet systems can barely reach 5 T *peak* strength (in a very limited area relative to system size).

Comment: I just found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rrN1vgA8to They claim to use permanent magnets to move at least seemingly heavy loads. What would make it impractical for passenger use?

Comment: What they have done is light compared to what passenger trains use. In terms of small-scale passenger transport (maybe small, lightweight cars/pods or the such?) it might be viable - the issue is that larger-scale operations are more demanding on the fields required, and permanent magnets just can not keep up. If you try to scale the system up, the quare-cube law kicks in, where the total force generated by a fixed system scales with the area of magnetic repulsion (square of the dimension scaling) but the total weight from the mass scales with the volume (cube of the dimension scaling).

Comment: In any case, magnetic levitation is already almost entirely economically limited by infrastructure investment costs rather than fuel costs - it is only just barely cost-viable on the highest throughput passenger routes. Passenger transport in particular since only high-speed transport sees significant fuel savings from less resistance, and passenger transport is the only high-volume time-sensitive transportation demand.

Comment: The fuel savings of a permanent magnet system is therefore of negligible benefit, while the additional infrastructure requirements since the system has less throughput (limited by magnet strength) is of much greater concern. Investors seem to agree, since the company that made that video seems to be defunct, and no major parties seem to be pursuing this technology.

Comment: What could save this is if there is a large breakthrough in permanent magnet strength. I don't know enough about physics in this area to know if that seems possible.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answers! I also thought that construction costs might be the biggest blocker for maglev trains in overall.

"Investors seem to agree, since the company that made that video seems to be defunct, and no major parties seem to be pursuing this technology."  Defunct might also be due to overall business skills, but most likely other similar ventures would have popped up if the technology had real potential.

Btw, apparently some hyperloop projects explore partially passive levitation as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGf5ewSm-4c